# Hash links not working on mobile when refreshing or returning to page

Tags: html, mobile, anchor, hashlink

I'm using the following to send the user to a new page where the browser should automatically scroll to a designated section:

`<a href="publications.html#podcasts" target="_top">`

The designated section of the destination page is tagged like this:

`<p id="podcasts" name="podcasts">`

Everything works as it should on a desktop browser. It also works on a mobile device, initially. On Chrome for Android, once the destination page has been visited, the hash link is ignored on a page refresh or revisit, instead landing the user at the top of the page. I can't confirm whether this occurs on other mobile browsers, and while there appears to be some online discussion about the issue, I can't find a workaround. I tried adding 'name' as well as 'id' but the issue persists.